# Characters of Linear Algebraic Groups

Tags: representation-theory, characters, invariant-theory, quiver

Reading about the semi-invariants of quivers, I see a fact which is frequently referred to in the literature, and is assumed to be trivial. However, I don't see that very easily.
So, I was wondering if you could let me know if there is a crystal clear fact that I missing here.

For a given finite quiver $Q$ and a fixed dimension vector $\alpha$, it is claimed that every character of the algebraic group $\operatorname{GL}(Q,\alpha)$, namely every morphism of algebraic groups $\psi: \operatorname{GL}(Q,\alpha) \rightarrow K^*$, is of the form
$\{A(x)|x \in Q_0\} \rightarrow \prod _{x\in Q_0}$ $(\det A(x))^{\sigma(x)}$, where $\sigma$ is a weight (one dimensional irreducible representation) of $\operatorname{Rep}(Q,\alpha)$.

It would be a great help if you could let me know whether this result is derived, as a corollary, from a general fact about the characters of algebraic groups of the given form, which I am not aware of.

Comment: It is enough to check that any morphism of algebraic groups $\operatorname{GL}_n \to K^\times$ is a power of $\det$. This is a rather well-known fact.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).